# How to add authorization and content type in URL

Tags: java

I am trying to make REST call to Fusion Table API . I am using spring Template for REST

When i am defining my URL as :

```
String URI = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/fusiontables/v1/tables/tableid/import";
```

**Exception :**

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized
```

which is fine and means that its hitting google server .

But when i use :

```
URL  :String URI = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/fusiontables/v1/tables/tableid/import"+"&Authorization:""&Content-Type: application/octet-stream";
```

its throwing execption :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found
```

Which I am not able to comprehend .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are appending the request headers to your URL string, which is incorrect. These two headers:

- Authorization: ""
- Content-Type: application/octet-stream

Should ***not*** be added to the request URL. Instead, if your using Apache HttpComponents:

```
final HttpPost post = new HttpPost();
post.addHeader("Authorization", "");
post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
```

Or alternatively, with HttpUrlConnection:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
```

Or alternatively, with Spring RestTemplate:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Authorization", "");
headers.add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(helloWorld, headers);
```

There's a ton of information on Spring specific options on their documentation pages for [RestTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#postForLocation%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) and [HttpEntity](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.html).

Comment: i am using rest template of spring

Comment: When I looked in their doc (Spring template) I could find anything which could help add authorization in the URL .